# Prevent eval from exiting the program

Tags: php, eval

I am trying to create a PHP "editor", so, I have a form with the PHP editor and a file that processes the code that was submitted as input and returns as an object.

In order to catch some data like the execution time and buffer length, I need to get them after the code was evaluated. The problem here is that if the user killed the program's execution with `die` it won't get that information.

This the file that processes the submitted code:

```php
<?php

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
require_once $path . '/wp-load.php';

require WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/php-editor/vendor/autoload.php';

$output = [];
$data = json_decode( file_get_contents( "php://input" ), true );

// Remove E_WARNING from output
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

if ( $data['data'] ) {
    ob_start();
    $start_time = microtime(1);
    
    try {
        // Execute client's code
        eval( $data['data'] );
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $output['output'] = 'N/A';
    }    

    // Generate response
    $output['output'] = ob_get_contents();
    $output['execution_time'] = number_format(microtime(1) - $start_time, 2, '.', '') * 100 . 'ms';
    $output['buffer_length'] = number_format((float)ob_get_length(), 0, ',', '.') . 'B';
    ob_end_clean();

    // Return response as Pretty JSON
    echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

If the user submits `var_dump("test"); die;` (for instance), whatever comes after is not displayed since the program was stopped from running with the `die()` function (even after catching it) and the `$output` object is not returned. Any suggestions on how to prevent this?

Comment: So this is a user you trust enough to execute random scripts on your server, but don't trust enough not to call `die()`?

Comment: “Warning, exiting the program early through die or exit might cause metrics to not be accurate”

Comment: I guess you might be able to use this, too: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uopz-allow-exit.php

Comment: Is there something preventing you from validating their data? Is `$data['data']` not just a string? Can you just check the contents of their data before evaluating it? Something like `str_replace("die()", "", $data['data'])`. This is just many ways that you can perform validation on their input. If it's not a string, there's still ways to validate.

Comment: Well, @RobbyCornelissen, yes and yes, the user is a developer and uses the program under his own risk... But killing the program will kill also my program.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, yes, that might work. Warn the user so we quit any responsabilities is always a great option.

Comment: You could also write the PHP to a file and execute it in its own process which would isolate it from your code completely

Answer (score 0):

Well, I should thank ChatGPT for this answer but since he is not replying yet I have changed my code to this:

```php
<?php

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
require_once $path . '/wp-load.php';

require WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/php-editor/vendor/autoload.php';

$output = [];
$data = json_decode( file_get_contents( "php://input" ), true );

// Remove E_WARNING from output
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

// Custom output buffer handler
function output_handler($buffer) {
    global $output;
    global $start_time;
    
    $output['output'] = $buffer;
    $output['execution_time'] = number_format(microtime(1) - $start_time, 2, '.', '') * 100 . 'ms';
    $output['buffer_length'] = number_format((float)strlen($buffer), 0, ',', '.') . 'B';
    
    return json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}

if ( $data['data'] ) {
    ob_start('output_handler');
    $start_time = microtime(1);
    
    try {
        // Execute client's code
        eval( $data['data'] );
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $output['output'] = 'N/A';
    }
    
    ob_end_flush();
}
```

What we've done here is replace `ob_start()` with `ob_start('output_handler')`. The `output_handler` function is called automatically before the script exits, which allows you to calculate the metrics even if the user exits the program with `die` or `exit`. Finally, we have replaced `ob_end_clean()` with `ob_end_flush()` to flush the buffer and send the response to the client.